# With clang, template methods in derived class hide parent's methods with same name, even if disabled by SFINAE and even with using-declaration

Tags: c++, clang++, sfinae, name-hiding

Please, have a look at this small sample code

```
#include <type_traits>

struct base {
    template <typename T>
    int func(T);
};

struct derived: base {
    using base::func;

    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,const char*>>* = nullptr>
    int func(T);
};    

auto x = derived().func(1);
```

It compiles fine with gcc and icc, it doesn't with clang, which complains like this:

```
<source>:17:20: error: no matching member function for call to 'func'

auto x = derived().func(1);
         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~

<source>:13:9: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_same_v<int, const char *>' was not satisfied [with T = int]

    int func(T);
        ^
```

As if no `using-declaration` were added to `struct derived`. If I weren't using templates, I'd for sure know that this would be clang's problem. However, I am not sure the fact I'm using templates and SFINAE implies different rules got to be used, so here's my question: **which compiler is right? Clang, or gcc and icc?**

Here's a working example of the issue on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/xv98SP

Comment: I was about to issue a bug report to clang, then I noticed somebody had reported the issue already, about 2 years ago. It's still in NEW state since then and, reading the related discussion (and following the link therein) it seems that there's no conclusion about whether that's really a bug or not.

Here's the bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39581